# Accessing and storing viewController variables in appDelegate

Tags: ios, swift

Here's my problem: I have several variables in my viewController, for example:

```
var money = 0.0
```

I want to store this value on the device as soon as the app is going to terminate. To do this, I need to be able to acces the variable in the appDelegate and use it in 'applicationWillTerminate'. I then want it to be stored on the device and when the app restarts I want to be able to acces the stored value again. How do I do this in (swift) Xcode 8.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"applicationWillTerminate" as Apple docs say, is no more called in modern app unless You set a specific flag in plist.
The correct approach is to store values in NSUserDefault:

For swift 3.0:

1) let's create a class to manage money, and saving them:

```
class MoneyManager: NSObject {

    private let MONEY_KEY = "money"

    static let sharedInstance = MoneyManager()

        var money: Float? {
        get {
            let returnValue  = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: MONEY_KEY) as? Float
            return returnValue
        }

        set(newValue){
            if newValue == nil {
                UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: MONEY_KEY)
            } else {
                UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue!, forKey: MONEY_KEY)
            }

            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        }
    }
}
```

2) to use it in every controller you need:

```
let money = MoneyManager.sharedInstance.money
if money == nil{
    MoneyManager.sharedInstance.money =  1000
}
```

As every time we call UserDefaults.standard.synchronize(), we are safe everything is saved.

Comment: If this value needs to be secure then I would consider looking into Keychain, also using the above method to save the value every time it's updated. To rely on a single app event could result in lost data, such as the app crashing and therefore no app delegate event being fired.